# Fully clickable button issues in Outlook emails

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to create a button that is 100% clickable (not just the text), is left aligned in desktop and full width in mobile, and is compatible with Outlook. I have tried all kinds of buttons, bulletproof, bombproof, VML etc. and I can't seem to get this to work with these requirements in Outlook. Anyone know how I can get a button to be fully clickable, left aligned in desktop and full width in mobile without compromising padding, position etc?

Comment: Have you tried putting the button in a wrapper that's fully clickable or simulating a button?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, but there has always been an issue

Answer (score -1):

Please go through below the link and use code VML buttons method. it will work entire button clickable for outlook.

https://www.activecampaign.com/blog/email-buttons